# UnsatisfiedLinkError in Processing

Tags: processing, jna

I have recently overcome this problem using eclipse and would like to use the same .dll in the Processing.org environment.  Here is my recent post on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698561/why-do-i-get-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-unable-to-load-library).

The .dll I want to use is in the `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\\` folder, but I am still getting an `UnsatisfiedLinkError`. I have tried the following solutions with no success:

- Adding the .dll to the 'code' folder of the sketch
- Adding `C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\foo.dll` to the Path environment variable
- Changing the Native.loadLobrary parameter in my code from `C:\\Windows\\System32\\foo.dll` to `C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\foo.dll`

To get this working in eclipse, I added a Native Library Location under the Libraries tab in the Java Build Path Properties, although I didn't think it should have been necessary.

I would be grateful for any help or suggestions.

Comment: From [the wiki page for WoW64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64), it appears that you don't want to reference the SysWOW64 folder directly: *When executing 32-bit applications, WoW64 transparently redirects 32-bit DLLs to %SystemRoot%\SysWoW64, which contains 32-bit libraries and executables. 32-bit applications are generally not aware that they are running on a 64-bit operating system. 32-bit applications can access %SystemRoot%\System32 through the pseudo directory %SystemRoot%\sysnative.*

Comment: Are you running 32-bit or 64-bit?  Is the DLL a system dll (if not, it should not be saved in SysWOW64)?  Is your DLL 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: Thanks for your responses!!  The .dll is 32 bit.  I suspect that the problem is that Processing is running a 64 bit jdk.  I'll look into it tonight and report back.